# Why say tachanun in mincha on 13 Iyar if you won't on 14 Iyar?

Tags: halacha, tachanun, pesach-sheni

Usually one does not say tachanun at mincha before a day when tachanun is not said. The Artscroll siddur says to say tachanun on the 13th of Iyar, the day before Pesach Sheni (the 14th of Iyar), even according to those who don't say tachanun on Pesach Sheni itself.  What is the logic or basis for this rule?

Comment: Maybe because the whole skipping Tachanun on Pesach Sheni thing is all made up recently anyway so הבו דלא לוסיף עלה we don't extend it further then necessary?

Answer (score 4):

From R' Dov Lior's answer at [Yeshiva.org.il](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/26979):

> הסיבה לכך היא, שכל עניין "פסח שני" מתחיל מהבוקר ואין שום עניין בלילה. את קרבן פסח שני עשו בבוקר, ובלילה לא עושים שום דבר (בניגוד לשאר חגים). ולכן כל העדות צריכות לומר תחנון.‏
>
> The reason for this is that the whole concept *Pesach sheini* starts from the morning and there is nothing related to the evening. The sacrifice of *Pesach sheini* was done in the morning* and in the evening nothing is done (unlike other holidays). Therefore, all communities have to say *tachanun.*
>
> <sub>*Own rough translation*</sub>

* [Bemidbar 9:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0409.htm#3) tells us that the sacrifice was actually performed in the afternoon:

> בְּאַרְבָּעָ֣ה עָשָֽׂר־י֠וֹם בַּחֹ֨דֶשׁ הַזֶּ֜ה **בֵּ֧ין הָֽעַרְבַּ֛יִם** תַּֽעֲשׂ֥וּ אֹת֖וֹ בְּמֹֽעֲד֑וֹ כְּכָל־חֻקֹּתָ֥יו וּכְכָל־מִשְׁפָּטָ֖יו תַּֽעֲשׂ֥וּ אֹתֽוֹ׃

Also if you carefully read the wording of [Orach Chayim 131:6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%95), a list is given there, so not saying *tachanun* on the afternoon preceding a holiday is not a general rule. We don't say it before ט"ו באב, ט"ו בשבט, Rosh Chodesh and most before Chanukkah, while Erev Rosh Hashanah ([Orach Chayim 581:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%90_%D7%92)) and Erev Yom Kippur ([Orach Chayim 604:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%93_%D7%91)) are exempted on their own right.

Whether one should say *tachanun* or not on *Pesach sheini* is discussed in depth with a very detailed list of sources by R' Ephraim Grunblatt in [Rivevot Efraim חלק ו' סימן רנ"ח](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1084&st=&pgnum=346).

<sub>Thanks to [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) for discovering the imprecision!</sub>

Comment: To what do you refer when you say "unlike other holidays". What is done in the evening, erev other holidays?  No sacrifices were brought in the evening, erev of any day, whether or not the coming day was a holiday.

Comment: @YehudaW When were you supposed to eat the Paschal lamb?

Comment: How is Pesach sheni different from other days before which we do not say tachanun?  What observances are there for erev rosh hodesh, for example?